# .NET 5 MySql TypeInitializationException: CodeBase is not supported on assemblies loaded from a single-file bundle

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5, .net-core-publishsinglefile, typeinitializationexception

Simple console application, that should insert data to MySql database fails if published with single-file configuration:

```
    dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true -o publish/ GarLoader.MySqlUploader
```

If I then run it (`./publish/GarLoader.MySqlUploader`), it fails. The stack trace is:

```
      System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception.
       ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' threw an exception.
       ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize
       ---> System.NotSupportedException: CodeBase is not supported on assemblies loaded from a single-file bundle.
         at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_CodeBase()
         at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
         at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
         at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.get_ConfigPaths()
         at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.GetStreamName(String configPath)
         at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.get_IsAppConfigHttp()
         at System.Configuration.Internal.DelegatingConfigHost.get_IsAppConfigHttp()
         at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem..ctor()
         at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem()
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem()
         at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
         at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
         at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration..cctor()
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration.get_Settings()
         at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager..cctor()
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager.IsReplicationGroup(String groupName)
         at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
         at SqlWorker.ASqlWorker`1.Exec(String command, DbParametersConstructor parameters, Nullable`1 timeout, CommandType commandType, IDbTransaction transaction)
         at GarLoader.MySqlUploader.Inserter`1.InsertAddressObjectTypes(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 items)
         at GarLoader.MySqlUploader.Inserter`1.InsertItems(String connectionString, IEnumerable`1 items)
         at GarLoader.MySqlUploader.UploaderToMySql.InsertAddressObjectItems[T](IEnumerable`1 items)
         at GarLoader.Engine.Updater.LoadGlobalEntry[T](ZipArchive arch, String entryBeginingSubname, Func`2 prepareItem)
         at GarLoader.Engine.Updater.Update(DownloadFileInfo downloadFileInfo)
         at GarLoader.Engine.Updater.Update()
```

It runs fine if it is launched by `dotnet run` without publishing.

Is there any workaround so I could build it as single-file application and run ?

Comment: this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68298059/why-does-my-net-web-api-application-not-connect-to-mysql-on-docker-when-using-d  

The .NET MySQL library you are using (MySql.Data) is dependent on ConfigurationManager, which is causing this exception.

Comment: Let me know if it works for you. You need to use /p:SelfContained=True /p:PublishProtocol=FileSystem in place of /p:PublishSingleFile=true

Comment: thanks, @viveknuna, publishing with your parameters resulted to working application!
But now there are 249 files instead of one...

Comment: @obratim it should be like this only, is there any issues with this?

Comment: @obratim which MySQL client and version are you using? .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5, while `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` is a .NET Framework (aka .NET Old) class. You may need to use a newer client version or use a completely different client. Oracle's MySQL/Connector is ... idiosyncratic shall we say. After all, Oracle has no reason to make .NET's life easier. [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector) may be a better alternative. It's used by the most popular EF provider for MySQL

Comment: @obratim I remember running into similar problems when I used Oracle's driver in a tool project that I also wanted to package as a single file. Suddenly, the project started to download a ton of compatibility libraries I had no use for *and* causing publishing problems. I switched to MySqlConnector immediatelly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short Version**

Use [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) instead of Oracle's `MySql.Data`.

**Why**

I suspect you're using Oracle's MySQL/Connector driver. This driver has *several* problems and using `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` is one of the lesser ones.

`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` is part of .NET Framework, while .NET 5 is actually .NET *Core* 5. To use it, you have to install a compatibility library, meant only to help migrating .NET Framework applications that used `app.config`. Instead of releasing a proper .NET Core package, Oracle simply retargeted the .NET Framework package using compatibility libraries.

Worse problems are the inefficient async support and the infrequent releases, which means bugs take several months if not years to get fixed.

A better option, which would solve your current problem, is to use the [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) package. It has *no* dependency on compatibility packages in .NET Core (actually, it has no dependencies, period).

Beyond that:

- it's a true community-built OSS project, as popular as Oracle's own driver (24M downloads vs 29M downloads),
- it's faster with true asynchronous methods
- It's used by the most popular Entity Framework provider, [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/)  - 15M downloads to Oracle's 3M downloads.
- Both packages are actively maintained and have already released previews for EF Core 6 and .NET Core 6.
- It's worth repeating - no dependencies on .NET Core/.NET 5/6.

Comment: Sadly, MySqlConnector stopped working for me after upgrading mysql from 5.6 to 5.7.

Comment: Brilliant. Not only did I notice a speed improvement but the single file package size was cut down by half. I am not 100% sure if its because I binned the Mysql.Data or because I updated all the packages to NET 6 but the combination works well.. Plus it solved the problem the OP was saying. +1000 

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `/p:SelfContained=True /p:PublishProtocol=FileSystem` in place of `/p:PublishSingleFile=true`

Comment: The question's point is how to fix the error *without* disabling single file publishing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please guide me if you can help in providing the solution